# calculating big o of my function

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I am learning about Big O and need some help calculating the big O of my function.

I need to find out the big O if self is of size s and other is of size o

I am not sure about the complexity of calling the has function as i know the for loop in intersection will be complexity of S

but will the complexity of has() be of size o? as id imagine it having to loop through o until it finds a match or returns false.

The data types of self and other that are being used are positive and negative ints

```
 def has(self, item):

        return item in self.items

    def intersection(self, other):
        common = Set()
        for item in self.items:
            if other.has(item):
                common.add(item)
        return common
```

Comment: This depends a bit on the data type you use for `self.items`. What is it? Have a look here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: there's a built-in `insersection` method in `set` BTW.

Comment: the data types that will be used will be both positive and negative ints ill add that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity for checking if value is in list would be `O(n)` (it'll have to loop). Time complexity for checking if value is in set would be `O(1)` - it'll compute a hash and check whether there is a value for this hash in a set. You may write your own class that implements `in` where time complexity would be related to your own implementation. You cannot answer this question without knowing definition of `other`.

Comment: other is just another data set which contains positive and negative ints, thanks for your answer

Comment: @bighead but what's the type of `items`? What happens when you invoke `type(items)`?